# Zero Input rate in Spark file streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using `textFileStream` for streaming data from Amazon s3. It gives me output only for the first batch. In addition to that, input rate in Spark UI is always zero. My question is similar to [Spark Streaming: Input Rate and File stream [0] has "Avg: 0.00 events/sec" always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195402/spark-streaming-input-rate-and-file-stream-0-has-avg-0-00-events-sec-alway)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I witness the same behavior.
My guess is that the UI is basing these metrics on receivers and since textFileStream is not actually back by a receiver ( 
"[file streams do not require running a receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers)" ), the number is ( wrongly ) 0.
This makes sense as the same behavior is [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070118/spark-streaming-kafka-createdirectstream-spark-ui-shows-input-event-size-as-ze) when using the Kafka stream which also is not backed by a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

EMR and their s3:// or Apache Spark and the s3n/s3a clients?

Comment: I have created cluster using Amazon EMR  and files are streams from Amazon S3.

Comment: not my code then, can't help. Try cranking up the logging in the spark and aws libraries to debug and see what's actually going on,